# Perl use regex to split a line

Tags: html, regex, perl, split

I'm trying to split the line below where there is a `<br />`,`<br>` and commas to push that into an array. I need to get the days which are LUN - JUE, VIE, SAB and DOM, and also the hours that correspond to them. I started learning perl yesterday and got stuck with this and need help.

These are the instructions of what i have to do so I'm not sure if I can make use of split.

> 3. Make a Perl script or program that uses regular expressions to read the test file, extract movie names and showtimes, and create an html
>      file to display the extracted data.

This is what I have tried which I know I'm not even close.

```
@hours = $row.split(/[<br \/><br>]+/);
```

&

```
elsif($row =~ qr{(.+)<br />(.+),(.+),(.+)<br>(.+)<br />}){
      @hours = $1;
      print "@hours\n";
}
```

This is the line I'm trying to split.

```
LUN - JUE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM<br>VIE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>SAB <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>DOM <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM <br/>
```

Comment: ***“I started learning perl yesterday”*** This isn't a site to help you learn Perl. Once you are accomplished in the language, and come across a problem that you can't resolve, then you should come here and ask about it. Stack Overflow is intended to be a *knowledge base* of programming problems. If you simply don't know the language then there are better places to look for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `@hours = $row.split(/[<br \/><br>]+/);` is invalid `perl` syntax.

Second, `[<br \/><br>]` will not work for you, because it will consider every character independently rather than as a group.

So, you should use grouping in `regex`. But in `split` when you keep delimiter in group, then the group  also gets captured in result-set, so to remove it, keep `(?:)` i.e non capturing group.

This will work for you:

```
my $string='LUN - JUE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM<br>VIE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>SAB <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>DOM <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM <br/>';

my @array=split(/(?:<\s*br\s*\/\s*>|<\s*br\s*>)+/i,$string);
```

Keeping `\s*` will handle all cases, where you have multiple spaces inside `br` tag.

For more understanding, you should learn [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) and [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit your answer? i wanna be able to fully understand it, and thanks.

Answer (score -1):

#### This script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sample = 'LUN - JUE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM<br>VIE <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>SAB <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM, 11:10 PM<br>DOM <br /> 10:30 AM, 1:40 PM, 4:50 PM, 8:00 PM <br/>';

my $line_re = qr/\s*\Q<br\E\s*\/?\Q>\E\s*/i;
my $day;
my %lookup;

for my $line ( split($line_re, $sample) ) {

  $line =~ s/^\s+|\s*$//g;
  $day = $line if(!defined $line || $line =~ m/^[a-z]/i);

  if ( $line =~ m/^\d/ ) {
    my @times = split(/,/, $line);
    $lookup{$day} = [@times];
  }
}

print Dumper \%lookup;
```

#### Which outputs

```
$VAR1 = { 
          'VIE' => [ 
                     '10:30AM',
                     '1:40PM',
                     '4:50PM',
                     '8:00PM',
                     '11:10PM'
                   ],
          'SAB' => [ 
                     '10:30AM',
                     '1:40PM',
                     '4:50PM',
                     '8:00PM',
                     '11:10PM'
                   ],
          'LUN-JUE' => [ 
                         '10:30AM',
                         '1:40PM',
                         '4:50PM',
                         '8:00PM'
                       ],
          'DOM' => [ 
                     '10:30AM',
                     '1:40PM',
                     '4:50PM',
                     '8:00PM'
                   ]
        };
```